# Apache redirect & rewrite

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

This is my page
**http://example.com/index.html** .
I would like to make it work like this.

- I would like to take the user to http://def.com when he requests
  http://example.com/index.html
- Even if he requests http://example.com/index.html?headers=0, he should be taken
  to http://def.com
- But if he requests the same URL with other query parameters, say for example http://example.com/index.html?footer=1, then the redirect or rewrite shouldn't happen. He should still be seeing the response from http://example.com/index.html?footer=1

I have already tried

```
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
    RewriteRule ^/index.html$ http://def.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your htaccess file to this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(headers=0|)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://def.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi, Now what if I need to match anything that doesn't contain the query string headers?                                                                                             I tried                                                                                             RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(!headers)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://def.com [R=301,L]                                                                                                                         but this doesn't work.

Comment: @akimran82  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^headers

Comment: Thanks @sreedev-s-b. But I would like it in the same was as the previous one. So can I change it to RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(headers=0|)$ [NC]     I now want to rewrite/redirect if there is no query string OR if the query string doesn't contain the parameter headers

Comment: @akimran82 see my second answer

Answer (score 1):

Change your htaccess file to this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !headers
RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://def.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The below commands worked for me actually                                                                 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !headers
RewriteRule ^index.html$ http://def.com [R=301,L]